# Javascript / jQuery, create new $collection and push elements on to $collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find some elements and change some propertise on them multiple places in my code, the only issue, is that i need to find these elements by splitting a data-attribute into an array.

Example, i am given a choice_id, every .question has an attribute with a bunch of choice_id's, inserted like this:

```
<div class="question" data-expanded-by="2,10,28">
<div class="question" data-expanded-by="2">
```

Say i am given the choice_id = 2, i assume i cannot write a selector for a collection like this

```
$('div.question[data-expanded-by=...])
```

So i wrote this small function to fetch me the elements and return them as a jQuery collection. The only issue is that calling $questions.show() on the returned value has no effect, even tho the collection is populated.

```
function findQuestionsExpandedByChoice($, $question_list, choice_id) {
    $questions = $([]);
    $.each($question_list.find('div.question[data-expanded-by]'), function() {
        ids = $(this).attr('data-expanded-by').split(',');
        if (isInArray(choice_id, ids)) {
            $questions.push($(this));
        }
    });
    return $questions;
}

function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

> EDIT
>   I forgot to mention i have the ability to save the data-expanded-by values as anything i want to, is there a smarter way to do this rather then saving them as , separated numbers? In a way that i can query them directly. To my understanding HTML does not support duplicate data attributes.

Comment: You don't need to create a jquery object of collection . Just create a regular array. $questions = [];

Comment: can i call .show() on a regular array? I thought that was a jQuery function which required a collection

Comment: 52d32fc_questionnaire_3.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: $questions.hide is not a function

Comment: On a collection, You can't. You need to extract the item in your collection. $(this).show()

Comment: Yes, but i am performing other operations on the collection other places in my code, such as $questions.find()